# Ebook file size connected to word

Tags: kindle, epub, publishing

I submitted my 180,000 word book to book baby having inserted images with the captions embedded alongside the pictures within the images. My first submission wound up being a 13.5 meg docx file. I rejected the proofs because the embedded caption text had bad edges and was not readable. And the Epub file was 8.03meg which I considered too big.

I reworked the images using different proportions (1500 x 1650px) and a larger font. And reduced the average file size from 2meg each for the first submission to 800k for the second. A total reduction form 58meg of pictures to 12meg. Unbelievably my .docx file size went up to 18.5meg and my new Epub file is 9.7meg. There were four more images inserted for the second go due to the reworking of proportions but

Comment: Please try to ask a specific question. What is your problem? What solution do you need?

Comment: Why do you find it unbelievable that a file format like .docx grows in size when you further edit on it? In my experience with Word file format this has been the case for over 20 years. 1) Try exporting, 2) update your post with information about what software you use to convert docx to Epub. 3) I removed the question marks on the non questions and the Help! from your post, but could not make sense of the last sentence, please rewrite/extend. And follow idiotprogrammer's advice (also by editing your post).

Comment: When images are embedded in DOCX or EPUB files, both files grow in size. All images have to be shipped with the EPUB file. To make the image files smaller, convert to 256 colors (if that's ok with you) and make the images smaller. I use [Irfanview (free)](http://www.irfanview.com/) for image conversion, resize, and changing color depth. Also in Word, do you have "tracking changes" turned on? That would make your DOCX file grow with each change.